# Executing "unicode" Python script from Gedit vs Terminal

Tags: command-line, python, gedit

As can be seen from screenshot, same script run from Terminal and Gedit behaves differently - in terminal script executes succesfully and in Gedit it raises error:

[image]

But if I change `python` in Gedit tool manager to `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python`, then script will execute fine also from Gedit

Why is this, and what setting in Terminal allows python "unicode" code to execute without issues?

---

Just to update as I added bounty: It's not just GEdit, but also in SciTE error is raised, but not in Geany as Geany executes Python scripts through terminal

Comment: you might want to read this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python and http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: Good read, thanks. So this issue can be treated as piping problem to Python interpreter for whatever reason, even thou encoding is declared in source file. I feel so sad that most friendly language in the world (IMHO) crawls to this Babylonian Unicode issues in so many ways, and it's so difficult to understand all possible implications, w/o need to be bother "decode early - encode later" - it's so un-pythonic (IMHO)

Comment: I feel the same way... But there is hope: as soon as enough libraries have switched to python3, we can actuallystart using it and everything will be alright :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal allows python "unicode" code to execute without issues because it has  `sys.stdout.encoding` correctly set.

I change the script as below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

print sys.stdout.encoding
print u"富强"
```

Run in Gedit, the output is: `None` for `sys.stdout.encoding`.

Run in Terminal, the output is `UTF-8` for `sys.stdout.encoding` and the string is printed correctly.

But if I change locale `LC_CTYPE` from `en_US.UTF-8` to `C`, run it in Terminal with `LC_CTYPE=C ./test.py`, I get the following:

```
ANSI_X3.4-1968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print u"富强"
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`sys.stdout.encoding` is set to ASCII so it cannot handle the string.